# A good book on topology for self-study

Tags: general-topology, self-learning, book-recommendation

What's a good book for self-study on a first topology course?
I'm taking topology for the first time, and my professor isn't what you might call great, everything is utterly easy or trivial for him, and almost never answers my questions, we're using the Munkres, but I wouldn't call it a great book, it's almost tasteless and I don't see the point to most or to any of its problems. I've heard it's a great book if you have a great teacher which sadly I don't. Sometimes he won't teach a whole section of the book and leave it to us to comprenhed it, but it still comes in the test.

So, what is a good book on topology for self-study? I don't just want to pass the class, I would like to get a grasp on the subject.

I know this has been asked before; but the last question I found similar to this is from 2010, maybe there's some new book?

Thank you.

Comment: The book of Munkres has been very important for me. I learned a lot there. Just my 2 cents

Comment: "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" by John Lee.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I don't doubt that, but maybe you had a better professor?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: Point set topology != Topological Manifolds. So don't expect to get the same topic coverage you'll require for your class.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what you're looking for that Munkres isn't supplying?Motivation? Examples? Maybe try `Experiments in Topology` by Stephen Barr if you need something more hands on to justify the learning.

Comment: I used Munkres for self-study and found the exercises comprehensive and the material well-motivated. Perhaps your professor is the barrier.

Comment: @Chickenmancer you're right, I think I miss the examples, the motivation and some solved problems and maybe the way the concepts the Munkres talk about connect to other stuff.

Comment: @CyclotomicField that might be it, too, I find myself not understanding a thing and not being able to ask anyone is downrigth frustrating.

Comment: Have you had real analysis? Munkres is the best topology book I have ever read but he starts with the definition of a topology which can seem arbitrary. Real Analysis is the course that motivates point set topology. The open sets in a metric space are the things that are generalized in topology.

Comment: @JohnDouma that's the other thing the College where I'm getting my degree has this Topology course as a requirement for the Real Analysis class.

Comment: You should also check: Counterexamples in Topology by Lynn Steen and J. Arthur Seebach, Jr. It isn’t a self-study book, but it is really helplful as a complement to a self-study book.

Comment: You might take a look at "Basic Topology" by Armstrong.

Comment: @Laci Thank you.

Comment: @awkward I'l give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite is Topology by James Dugundji (why do people answer in the comments?)

Comment: They don't think they have a definitive answer, so they comment over there, hehe.

Comment: Agreed, but we all like talking about our favorite books, and so we don't want to vote to close the question . . .

Comment: If one votes to close:
 
> Opinion-based

> This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.